# Creating inputs from array size not working with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to populate a list of `n` inputs from an `array` I have in `localStorage`. The issue is that I can see in `console.log()` that the for is getting executed but I only see two inputs.

**javascript:**

```
App.prefillWords = function() {
    var arrayWords = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("event-data")).selected_word;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayWords.length; i++) {
        var addto = "#field" + i;
        var addRemove = "#field" + (i);
        console.log(addto);
        console.log(addRemove);

        var newIn = '<input placeholder="Word" class="input form-control wordData" id="field' + i + '" name="field' + i + '" type="text">';
        var newInput = $(newIn);
        var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (i - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >-</button></div><div id="field">';
        var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
        $(addto).after(newInput);
        $(addRemove).after(removeButton);

        $("#field" + i).attr('data-source', $(addto).attr('data-source'));
        $("#count").val(i);

        $('.remove-me').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
            var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
            $(this).remove();
            $(fieldID).remove();
        });
    }

}
```

**html**

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
            <form class="wordsForm">
                <div id="field" class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right" for="wordScore">New Word</label>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6" id="fill">
                        <input autocomplete="off" class="wordData form-control" id="field1" name="prof1" type="text" placeholder="Word"/>
                        <button id="b1" class="btn add-more" type="button">+</button>
                     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <p class="text-right">
                  <button class="btn btn-space btn-primary" id="updateEvent">Submit</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-space btn-secondary" id="cancelEvent">Cancel</button>
               </p>
             </div>
          </form>
  </div>
```

**interface:**

[image]

Any advice is highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your HTML seems to start with a `#field1` input, but the first iteration of the loop creates a `#field0` input and tries to insert it after `#field0`, and so on.

Comment: I removed the #field1 and left the iteration run but is not working either @Aioros

Comment: You didn't have to remove it, you need to fix the logic of the loop. I'll try and post and answer.

Comment: There is no closing DIV tag for opening <div id="field"> ? maybe all the elements are inside the first div ?

Comment: Yeah, I actually started the answer and realized this is a little confusing. Are you trying to add a new div for each field too? There's a lot of things that need to be changed then.

Comment: can you also give an example of what the result of `localStorage.getItem("event-data")` looks like? It doesn't seem like you use the values of `arrayWords` in the loop, is that right?

Comment: I only want to add another input field with a button, I just copy some part of my html so I may missed a closing tag @Aioros